# Not able to convert NSString into NSDate properly

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am having trouble with date formatter. I am setting date format and passing the date string in the appropriate way (i think). But the result log shows some other dateand the GMT value has been lost. What am I doing wrong here ? Can anyone help me out here ?

```
  NSDateFormatter *newFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
  [newFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss zzz"];

  NSDate *lObjDate = [newFormatter dateFromString:@"2012-11-05 01:45:03 GMT+05:30"];

  NSLog(@">>>>> %@",lObjDate);
```

---

```
  >>>>> 2012-01-04 20:15:03 +0000
```

Comment: Code is behaving the right way. It is displaying the GMT date/ time. What is there that you are looking for. In this output, what is the date output you are expecting?

Comment: Evol Gate is correct, if you need to keep locale, set the newFormatter locale property to your preferred locale

Comment: @EvolGate is right,  what is the output you are expecting??

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z"];
```